# How to round rgb colors java

Tags: java, colors, rounding

I have a problem, from an image I need to get rgb color of each pixel but I don't want all the colors, for example

"If a pixel is a shade/tone of yellow" the function must return Color.YELLOW

"If a pixel is a shade/tone of blue" function must return Color.BLUE

Thanks for help in advance.

```
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelReader;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class ColorPicker {


private Image img;
private PixelReader pixels;

public ColorPicker(Image image) {
this.img=image;
pixels=img.getPixelReader();
}

public Color getColor(int row,int column) {
Color tmp= pixels.getColor(row, column);

return null;
}
```

Comment: You can check the pixel's RGB code and round the value according to the nearest end. For example if the given value in the range of 0-127 round to 0. If the value is in the 128-255 interval round to 255. This will work with the main colors. If you have to support more colors you can increase the granularity. (0-63 to 0, 64-127 to 127, 128-191 to 128 and so on).